# Can't loop a while loop

Tags: while-loop, python-3.6

So I want to do a while loop just to calculate the integral of some random functions. The thing is that when I pass opción = 1 it does the first if (good) but when I pass other number it breaks. Obviously, because True = 1 and False = 0. So how can I do it to do the while loop until (1,2,3) until I press 4... Thanks you so much in advance

```
while opcion == True:
        if opcion == 1:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x + b
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad1, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 2:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x**2 + b*x + c
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad2, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 3:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x**2 + d
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad3, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 4:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just wrap it into the while true then cause the break as expected and don't depent on option.  Use sys to just pass in the opcion as an argument for the script so that 4 will just cause it to break automatically... otherwise if its just generated into the script... you can have opcion generate a 1 by default to begin work.

```
import sys
...
opcion = sys.argv[1]
while True:
        if opcion == 1:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x + b
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad1, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 2:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x**2 + b*x + c
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad2, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 3:
            print('Vamos a calcular la siguiente integral:')
            f = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x**2 + d
            integral = sp.Integral(f, x)
            sp.pprint(integral)
            print()
            print('Que tiene como resultado:')
            sp.pprint(sp.integrate(f,x))
            print()
            print('Introducimos los límites y valores de las'
            ' constantes para caluclarla')
            lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
            lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            while (lim_inf == lim_sup):
                print('Los límites no pueden ser iguales !! '
             'Vuelve a introducir valores diferentes')
                lim_inf = int(input('Límite inferior = '))
                lim_sup = int(input('Límite superior = '))
            a = int(input('valor a = '))
            b = int(input('valor de b = '))
            res = integrate.quad(grad3, lim_inf, lim_sup, args=(a,b))
            print()
            print('Valor de la integral',res[0])

        elif opcion == 4:
            break
```